# Issue validating WebElement contents

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to validate that an expectedresult is on this page, but I keep getting an error message. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code I am running:

```
        string ActualResult;
        string ExpectedResult = "nH-brand-logo";
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("  ");
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("user_email")).SendKeys("  ");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("user_password")).SendKeys(" ");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("user_submit")).Click();
        ActualResult = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("nH-brand-logo"));
        if (ActualResult.Contains(ExpectedResult))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test Case Passed");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test Case Failed");
        }


        driver.Close();
        driver.Quit();



    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the HTML for the page you are trying to automate, and the error message you are receiving? This will help track down the issue.

Comment: Hey i want to validate that this logo is on the screen

Comment: Hey i want to validate that this logo is on the scree,  class="nH-brand-logo" and this is there error message im getting- CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement>' to 'string'

Comment: this is the html= <span _ngcontent-c1="" class="nH-brand-logo" mattooltip="Caseload" mattooltipclass="nH-logo-tooltip" mattooltipposition="below" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-0" cdk-describedby-host="" style="touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><img _ngcontent-c1="" class="" height="55px" src="assets/images/nH-icon.svg"><a _ngcontent-c1="" class="brand-logo">Coordinate</a></span>

Answer (score 1):

The code you’ve posted won’t compile, because you’ve declared `ActualResult` as a variable of type string, and `FindElements` returns a `ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>`, which is most decidedly *not* a string.

If you’re looking to find any element on the page where the `class` attribute contains "nH-brand-logo", then the following would be sufficient:

```
var elements = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("nH-brand-logo"));
bool testPassed = elements.Count > 0;
```

By calling the `FindElements` method in this way, if there are any elements returned, they each must, *by definition*, contain that value in their `class` attribute. Now, if you’re looking to validate something more complex than this, the full solution may be proportionally more complex.

Things to remember when working with Selenium:

- FindElement finds the element or throws an exception. If the element doesn’t exist, it does not return null or an empty value; it throws.
- FindElements returns all matching elements, or an empty list when no elements meet the find criteria. However, you do have to access the elements in the returned list to get information about any single element found.

Answer (score 0):

The line

> ```
> ActualResult = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("nH-brand-logo"));
> ```

will return a list of webElements, which you are then validating against a string. Hence the error.

> ```
>  string ActualResult;
>  string ExpectedResult = "nH-brand-logo";
>  if (ActualResult.Contains(ExpectedResult))
> ```

if you want to check if all the elements for ActualResults contains 'nH-brand-logo', then you can write

```
   bool result =  ActualResults.All(x=>x.GetAttribute("class").Contains('nH-brand-logo');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey i just want to validate that the brand logo exist on that part of the page

Comment: this is the html = <span _ngcontent-c1="" class="nH-brand-logo" mattooltip="Caseload" mattooltipclass="nH-logo-tooltip" mattooltipposition="below" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-0" cdk-describedby-host="" style="touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><img _ngcontent-c1="" class="" height="55px" src="assets/images/nH-icon.svg"><a _ngcontent-c1="" class="brand-logo">Coordinate</a></span>

Comment: var elements = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("nH-brand-logo")); Assert.True(element.Count == 1, "Logo was not found or more than one instance was found.")